# c# dataGridView random cells location change (Edit: Inter Process Synchronization?)

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, datatable

I have a dataGridView displaying data from DataView based on DataTable. DataTable is updated with high frequency from a background thread (usually one row a time) but with varying regularity, i.e. sometimes time between updates is 0.5 ms, other few miliseconds. As datagridview is bound to DataView, I do not send requests for refresh of datagridview.
The problem I am having is that I sometimes get cells drawn somewhere where they are not supposed to be, i.e. as seen in attached picture here: http://radlak.com/dataGridViewError1.png

The row with the number 122.94 has blue cell drawn in red column(gray column is PrimaryKey of DataTable, by which DataView is sorted). This is not supposed to happen, as the only blue cells should stay in second column. Sometimes, cell from third column will be displayed somewhere else. Would anyone know what is the reason of this kind of behavior?
Is there any way to eliminate it? Except of this, I do not have any issues with the speed of update - everything else seems to work very quick and ok.
I would greatly appreciate any help regarding this issue.
Thanks,
Martin

P.S. dataGridView1 is doublebuffered.

Answer (score 1):

It smells like a racing condition. The grid is not done swallowing one update and you hit it with another. Do you have any synchronization between the update process and the UI thread?

What might help is if you batch your updates and only apply them every once a while - i.e. every 100ms. After all it is UI for people to read there is no point in refreshing any faster.

**Edit**

One way of batching it would be to have the update thread apply updates to a separate data structure (a List? An Array?) and create yet another thread which would every .1 sec copy the modifications from the data structure to the UI.

The problems with locks you tried is that you applying the locks within your code does not do any good if the same objects are not locked inside the GridView. And GridView knows nothing about your locks

Comment: thanks very much, that is what I was thinking about too. Thats why I applied lock command whenever the row has been updated, but that seemed to be not enough. I tried to lock the whole table, dataview and datagridview, but that did not do the job either.

I think this is the part I am strugling with - synchronization. What would be the best way to do it? The key for me is to get to a point, when datagridview updates are correct without batching updates, and then batch them in order to achieve highest speed.
Thanks for help

Comment: Also, the update process is based on events occuring outside. whenever new data is available, an even function is called. This makes synchronization a bit more complicated, in such a way, that I am not sure how to wait with the new event to be processed until datagridview has been updated.

Comment: And lastly, I would certainly sacrifice datagridview updates in favour of event processing. I need datagridview to just check that everything is working fine.

Sorry for multiple comments but those ideas are comming to my mind in "batches" ;)

Comment: I think that this is what is missing: how to notify update process (which is waiting on monitor) about gui datagridview finished updating? Cant find it on google. Usually people are asking how to do it the other way round.

Comment: Maybe if you do updates on a timer with a reasonable rate, there will be no need to synchronize the timer thread with UI. You will still need to synch timer and updater, but both will be in your hands

Answer (score 0):

Can I query:

- you have a `DataTable`
- you have a `DataGridView`, bound to a `DataView` on that table
- on a **different thread**, you are updating the `DataTable`

?

Yes, that won't work. Forms have thread affinity, and your change events are going to be firing on the wrong thread. It is not OK to just update the `DataTable` on a background thread. It sounds to me like you need to think about batching up the changes you want to make, and use `this.Invoke` to ask the **UI thread** to make the changes; then it should work:

```
public override void OnDataArrival()
{
    // here on background thread
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
        // here on UI thread
        //TODO: update DataTable
    });
}
```

This will involve hopping between threads (via `this.Invoke`), hence the desire to batch the changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As shown in the code above, I am using Invoke to initialize datagrid, and what I noticed was, that once that invoke method has been succesfully executed, I do not have to repeat invoked updates from `OnDataArrival`. I assume that, once the datagridview received a reference to tbl, it stays there and does not require any further notifications. Seems like update events from DataTable after inoking `dDelegateInitializeGrid` notify datagridview correctly, however as I dont know how to take control over these events, they fire on every DataTable update creating racing conditions.

Comment: I am not sure if I explained one more thing accurately: when program starts its execution, first function that is being executed is `OnInitialization` in which I initialize Windows Form.

Comment: This is becoming more and more frustrating ... According to what I found on the internet, if datagridview sits in other thread than updating process, it should not reflect the changes in datasource. However, I have noticed, that by invoking `datagridinitialization` at the beginning, all changes in source are later reflected in the datagridview. Even if I dont want to. I tried using Merge on DataTable to make a copy of it, and update grid on timer, but still same thing happens - grid updates on every data arrival. Is it a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you have updates to a data-bound source on a non-UI thread, you have made a mistake...

Comment: I think that a lot of confusion in here is because UI is not a main thread, as everybody is used to. If it was the main one, I don't think there would be any problem.

Comment: I would look at something like your clone approach, but maybe using virtual mode to minimise to reset cost.

Comment: would you like me to post current state of the code? It includes timer in separate thread and copy of table?

Comment: Sorry, but threading issues are complex and subtle; there isn't enough there to reproduce what you are seeing, which makes it virtually impossible to give a meaningful answer beyond fairly broad pointers.

Comment: Ok, I will prepare something like a simulation of my core application and will post a code as soon as I will make it reproducing mentioned errors. This should be ready by tomorrow afternoon.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone would have a bit of time to look into the code, I have attached one which includes Timer in separate thread and form in a separate thread too:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public delegate void DelegateInitializeGrid(DataView tbl);

    public class MyMainClass : Strategy
    {
        RunForm runForm;
        Thread oThread;
        Thread tThread;

        public delegate void updateGridCallback(DataTable tbl);

        private DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        public DataTable ctbl = new DataTable();
        private DataView vtbl;
        public DataView cvtbl;
        DataRow dr;

        DataRow t;
        DataRow[] tt;

        System.Threading.Timer clock;
        bool frst = true;

        public override void OnInitialization()
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(double));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(int));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(System.Decimal));
            DataColumn[] PrimaryKeyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            PrimaryKeyColumns[0] = tbl.Columns["Price"];
            tbl.PrimaryKey = PrimaryKeyColumns;

            runForm = new RunForm();
            oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runForm.startForm));
            oThread.Start();

            tThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startTimer));
            tThread.Start();
        }

        void startTimer()
        {
            clock = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Timer_Tick));
            clock.Change(0, 1000);
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object state)
        {
            if (frst == true)
            {
                ctbl.Merge(tbl);
                cvtbl = new DataView(ctbl);
                cvtbl.Sort = "Price DESC";

                frst = false;

                runForm.sampleForm.Invoke(runForm.sampleForm.dDelegateInitializeGrid,
                    vtbl);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("tick occured");
            ctbl.Merge(tbl);
        }

        public override void onDataArrival()
        {
            //update DataTable tbl
        }

        public override void OnStop()
        {
            runForm.stopForm();
            clock.Dispose();
            tThread.Abort();

        }

    }    

    public class RunForm
    {

        public Form1 sampleForm = null;
        public DataTable dtbl;

        public void startForm()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            sampleForm = new Form1();
            Application.Run(sampleForm);
        }
        public void stopForm()
        {
            sampleForm.Dispose();
        }
    }



    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;



        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should bedisposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
                //aTimer.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // initialize form and datagridview

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;

        private void initializeGrid(DataView lst)
        {
            SetDoubleBuffered(dataGridView1);
            //this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public DelegateInitializeGrid dDelegateInitializeGrid;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dDelegateInitializeGrid = new DelegateInitializeGrid(this.initializeGrid);
        }

        public static void SetDoubleBuffered(Control control)
        {
            // set instance non-public property with name "DoubleBuffered" to true
            typeof(Control).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, control, new object[] { true });
        }
    }
}
```